# Можно ли вывести кастомные записи в перемешку со стандартными?

Tags: wordpress

Есть новостной сайт с множеством записей (постов). Возникла необходимость выделить часть постов в отдельный тип записей - "знаменитости".

1. Как переместить пост из стандартного в кастомный?
2. Как сделать так, чтобы на главной странице и в рубриках эти выделенные кастомные посты выводились совместно со стандартными?

Answer (score 0):

> Как переместить пост из стандартного в кастомный?

Наиболее просто с помощь плагина [Post Type Switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/) или аналогичного. Но есть нюансы с присвоением таксономий.

> Как сделать так, чтобы на главной странице и в рубриках эти выделенные
> кастомные посты выводились совместно со стандартными?

Например вёрсткой. Но это уже второй вопрос. По правилам SO один вопрос - одна проблема.